# How can we create different mapping for same entity in automapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I need to write mapping for an entity to its DTO for listing purpose and details view of an entity. But for listing I need to ignore a list property because of DTO because I don't want to load it, I have enabled Lazy loading in Entity framework. How can I create two mappings of same entity or add ignore for a property while querying data for list view.

```
cfg.CreateMap<page, PageViewModel>().ForMember(t => t.PageRows, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.page_rows)).
            ForMember(t => t.PageRules, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.page_rules.Select(x => x.rule_id)));
```

---

```
cfg.CreateMap<page, PageViewModel>().ForMember(t => t.PageRows, opts => opts.Ignore()).
            ForMember(t => t.PageRules, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.page_rules.Select(x => x.rule_id)));
```

Comment: You should create two different DTO types for your entity.

Comment: so no other solution :( ?

Comment: Why do you not want to create separate DTOs?

Comment: I was checking whether I can avoid a duplicate class creation

Comment: What AM method are you using for mapping? e.g. `Map`, `ProjectTo` etc.?

Comment: I know, I read your question.  I'm asking why you want to avoid that.

Comment: Ivan Stoev- Map

Comment: Amy, no specific reason, I don't like that :)

Comment: If you don't want to duplicate common properties in your DTOs, just try to use inheritance

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a `Precondition` with `Func<ResolutionContext, bool>` and then use the `Map` method overloads with `Action<IMappingOperationOptions>` to pass the controlling parameter through `Items` dictionary.

For instance:

```
.ForMember(t => t.PageRows, opts => 
{
     opts.MapFrom(s => s.page_rows);
     opts.PreCondition(context => !context.Items.ContainsKey("IgnorePageRows"));
})
```

and then:

```
IEnumerable<page> source = ...;
var withPageRows = Mapper.Map<List<PageViewModel>>(source);
var noPageRows = Mapper.Map<List<PageViewModel>>(source, 
    opts => opts.Items.Add("IgnorePageRows", null));
```

Reference: [**Conditional mapping**](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Conditional-mapping)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create two different DTO classes to map to.  If you do not want to do that, you also have another option which would be to create two marker interfaces and map to those.